# Need to resize the Ext.Window based on the control render on it

Tags: extjs

I need to resize my popup created by using `Ext.Window` based on the controls render on it.
I popup an aspx page and dynamically creating control on it. So i can't hard code the height of the window.

How can I resize the popup window height. Please help me with your valueable information.

My code is as follows.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var myWin = new Ext.Window({
        title: 'Add to Favourit',
        width: 380,
        height: 300,
        closable: true,
        buttonAlign: 'center',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'box',
                itemId: 'iFrameInWindow',
                title: 'IFrame',
                autoEl: {
                    tag: 'iframe',
                    src: 'forms/test.aspx?id=1'
                },
                flex: 1,
                width: 380,
                height: 300,
            }],
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function () {
                  //    
                },
            }

        }]
    });

    myWin.show();
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried panels layout `fit` property? And, don't set child elements width and height. If you need, just use `flex` property.

Comment: Hi Oguz, I have given layout to 'fit' for window and panel and also use flex to '1' then also it is not resizing based on the dynamically crated controls.

Comment: don't set windows layout to `fit`

Comment: both I tried. means with or without given fit to window and panel. but not resizing the window.